# Detecting VH on mobile in js and returning it's current value

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari, viewport, mobile-chrome

My issue is a hack for a dubious mobile browser discrepancy between the 100vh and the area hidden behind the mobile browser bars. This is a problem for any page where a full screen effect is desired.

The hack detects the difference between the VH and the actual visible viewport. However the simple js in the first code example appears to be detecting it backwards. So if the browser bar is overlaid the value should be 75 but is instead 0 -- likewise when the the browser is large it should return 0 but instead returns -75.

This can be reproduced simply by testing an iPhone with the 'develop' tool in Safari on google.com and entering this in the console.

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight - window.innerHeight
```

This seems to compute the shorter browser height with the top offset to compensate for the browser bar as being offset by 0 and the tall browser height where the browser bar is no longer covering the top of the page at -75px. This, to me, appears to be very wrong and should be 75 and 0 respectively. The below example is how I think it should work to properly offset the body tag to position elements with absolute positioning.

```
function fixIt(){
    var offset = (document.documentElement.clientHeight - window.innerHeight);
    document.body.style.marginTop = offset;
}
fixIt(); // run on resize
```

My extra super hacky solution it to offset the body by 75px by default and to assign the old value on vertical resize. (so when the browser bars hide, instead of 75px offset, use previous offset of 0 and save the 75px offset for the next resize). The works in Mobile Chrome and Mobile Safari, but for instance, if the link is opened in facebook where there is no browser bar and no resize events, it is offset by 75px permanently. This code is obviously insane and should be banished into the nothing.

```
var offset;
var oldOffset = 75px;
function fixIt(oldOffset){
    offset = (document.documentElement.clientHeight - window.innerHeight);
    document.body.style.marginTop = oldOffset;
    oldOffset = offset;
    return oldOffset;
}
fixIt(oldOffset); // run on resize
```

As an aside, or for further reading, here's a big complaint blog on the issue. https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html I agree with the browser vendors that VH should be constant (because the reflow would be obnoxious for everything besides the actual body height) but for the top level elements like body and html tags on mobile this behavior appears to be wrong and it makes no semantic sense, plus these computed numbers appear backwards, further making this issue headache inducing.

What other solutions are out there?